# How to query for similar words?

Tags: mariadb, levenshtein-distance

I'm not sure how I would accomplish this, but I have built an application in PHP with MariaDB. I want users to be able to search for a word, and exact results, and results similar show up.

For example, a recent one, a user typed **Adison** into the search box, and nothing came up. The real spelling is **Addison**.

I saw some answers based on Levenshtein Distance, but I figure there has to be a simpler solution

Comment: SOUNDEX would work for this particular example, but in general, this kind of thing is pretty complicated. Those other answers exist for a reason.

Comment: Generally we would create a function in mysql implementing the levenshtein distance function and then use that in the SQL statement testing for matches. I agree that if you are going to do name "sounds like" that implementing the SOUNDEX algorithm in a function would be a more appropriate solution. I've implemented SOUNDEX in an Access database before so it's not unreasonably difficult.

Comment: Just a remark. Soundex seems to work well for European/Western languages, but not for other languages.

Comment: This is an example of something that seems intuitive and simple to us humans but is very abstract and complex to computers.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I've figured that out lol. I don't need anything super advanced, but something so one or two letters still finds the actual word...I guess I'll try SOUNDEX and then release it, and if users still want more, i can try with the Levenshtein Distance function.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thats good to know. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @TheImpaler Soundex doesn't work well for English - the reality is that words in English rarely sound anything like the way they're spelt.

Comment: Should it be a multi language solution, or is limited to a specific language? And which language(s) ?

Comment: There is no good answer in MySQL for this problem.